# Exposing getter and setter from member with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I know how to generate setter and getter methods from member fields in eclipse. But is there a way to expose the setter and getter methods of a member with setter and getter?

For example if I have a class `Foo`:

```
class Foo
{
  private int val;
  public void setVal(int val)
  {
     this.val = val;
  }
  public int getVal()
  {
    return val;
  }
}
```

which is a member of the class `Foo2`:

```
class Foo2
{
  private Foo foo;
}
```

is it possible that I generate automatically with eclipse the following methods in the class `Foo2`?

```
public void setVal(int val)
{
  foo.setVal(val);
}

public int getVal()
{
  return foo.getVal();
}
```

Comment: why would you need those? in the end, all you really need is a getter/setter for Foo. if you do it like that, a using developer might mistakingly assume your Foo2 class contains a member val, which it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe [lombok `@Delegate`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Stultuske For the using developer it is not necessary to know if actually Foo2 or any other object in Foo2 contains the member val as long as he could set ang get this member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `Foo2` class in active editor window use `Source -> Generate Delegate Methods` menu item. Select `getVal()` and `setVal(int)` in the resulting window:

[image: Generate Delegate Methods]

Press OK.